# Can I omit "of them" in the following sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

> People filled the place, all (of them) chattering and blathering at a
>   volume that made my bones vibrate.

Can I? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "all" has been used in the sentence as a pronoun that refers to people. So you can use either all or all of them, without any difference in meaning.

Comment: I would say that it reads better without the "(of them)".

Answer (score 1):

I think it can, because it is quite clear what "all" refers to